# PHP not working with nginx on ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

Not working at all.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Returns blank. I googled for help, but still had no luck. 
I'm on Ubuntu 10.10, nginx/0.7.67. 
I used [this guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-php-5.3-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-debian) to set it up.
My error log has nothing useful.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you add to php.ini cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1? Also check nginx log there can be some valuable informations.

Comment: Make sure error reporting is turned on AND display errors is turned on in your php.ini.  Last time I had to install PHP with Apache I forgot that display_errors is set to off by default and I couldn't work out why my pages were broken (ended up being because somebody else had used short tags which I purposefully had turned off but the errors weren't showing up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why didn'nt you use the packages in the regular 10.10 repos?  I think you've followed the wrong how-to - that one is from 2010-02-08, i.e. before Ubuntu 10.10.  I'm on 10.10, and I can see the following packages, I think these are the ones you need:

```
$ apt-cache search --names-only php5-fpm
php5-fpm - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
$ apt-cache search --names-only nginx
nginx - small, but very powerful and efficient web server and mail proxy
```

Comment: I got it! It was my fault. Apparently I can't run php in a .html file. Making a phpinfo.php in the same directory solved everything.