# Getting a blank page on Wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a Wordpress blog which was working fine until I updated my PHP 5.3 to 5.5. Now the whole blog is blank. I cannot view the admin page or even the log in page. I have tried to fix it after searching a lot on Google, but it is still not working.

I have gone through these solutions:

- http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/common-wordpress-errors-with-solutions/
- http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/my-wordpress-blog-is-blank/

As stated in these solution the main reason is either a faulty theme or a plugin. So I changed my plugin folder to plugins_temp but still got that blank page. Then I changed my themes folder to themes_temp and still I got that same problem.

In the first link that I have submitted here there was this solution `# 3 Warning: Cannot modify Header information` where they proposed a solution i.e wp-config.php will have a blank line after the php '?>' closing tag. I looked at my wp-config.php and there was no closing tag '?>'. So I added that tag without a blank line and that still didn't solve that blank page issue.

I have another PHP website on a different subdomain and it is working fine. In my blog's root folder there is readme.html and when I use this url (myblog/readme.html) then that file gets displayed on the browser so only none of the PHP files are getting rendered.

Lastly I did try to install a totally fresh Wordpress site but when I go to install.php then none of the files are being executed.

I am using php5-fpm, Ubuntu 12.04 and NginX.

Comment: Check your error log i think something fatal error or share of link

Comment: I did check my error log but I dont see any error. blog.learning-outcomes.com

Comment: no issue simple chmod 777 -R folder name or set permission

Comment: 5.5? Are you sure? - that's only alpha release at the moment. Use 5.4 if you want to be up-to-date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try turning on debugging mode?

You do that in *wp-config.php*.

Locate `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and set it to true.

Another thing I would try is to make some simple php file and test that if it is working. Something like:

```
<?php

echo "test";

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you probably have problem with php itself, check this question on stackoverflow [php not working with nginx on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059194/php-not-working-with-nginx-on-ubuntu):

Comment: yes I did try that but still the issue persists. I have looked into my error.log and php5-fpm log but there is nothing there related to wordpress.

Comment: that is not working I did try that. and also the last method proposed here http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/my-wordpress-blog-is-blank/

Comment: So that simple php file (with echo "test") is also not working?

Comment: yes thats not working and it is strange because I have another website on different subdomain and it is written in php and that is working

Comment: In that simple php file try removing php in <?php so that opening tag only consists of only <?

Comment: I did that too but still the result is the same

Comment: Then you need to find out why php is not working. I added a link to a question that is similar to your problem. If that also doesn't help  try asking another question this time focusing on php, ubuntu, nginx.

Comment: but I think php is working because that test.php file I added to the root of another sub domain php application and it does outputs the string "test" it is just not working with wordpress. Even the foo.html files are getting rendered.

Comment: Maybe php is not configured properly. I suggest to make another question, this time about why simple php file is not working on domain, but works on subdomain with nginx on ubuntu.

Comment: ok I finally figured it out. I wrote a new nginx vhost and it finally got working. I saw that blank screen error and started looking out in that regard and came upon those articles which I had earlier listed here, but it was php5-fpm which wasnt able to find those php files in that particular subdomain. Anyway thanks a lot for your help I couldnt have figured it out on my own.

Answer (score 3):

### Some common solutions

1. **define('WP_DEBUG', false); set to TRUE** - wordpress turns off the
   error reporting, thats why you get white screens. Turning this on
   would show the error messages.
2. **error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');** - if solution above doesnt work, you can manually add this in your wp-config or to the template file that broke down.
3. if everything else fails, then you can try tracing the code with something like, **die('runs till here')**. It's a pretty back breaking method but it will surely point you where problem is. I did this once and found out later that the white screen was caused by a **memory limit exceeded** error. This kind of error can't be seen with solution 1 & 2.

Comment: Thank for some great suggestions, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` works great for me!

Answer (score 1):

Check your errorlog, most probably one of the installed plugins isn't compatible with PHP 5.5
Try to find out which one, and disable it via the wordpress database or the filesystem:
http://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/disable-a-wordpress-plugin/